# Problem on merging two columns in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm trying to merge two columns in a `dataframe` in python. The original `dataframe` is like this:

```
    type    id      details                details2
0   hotel   df9466  #2 in the rank of 288       nan
1   hotel   gt9444  #48 in the rank of 340      nan
2   hotel   dfa887  #12 in the rank of 7414     nan
3   hotel   fgfd81  nan                     #1 in rank of 8792
4   hotel   fsf887  nan                     #70 in rank of 245
```

And my expected result should be like this:

```
    type    id          details                
0   hotel   df9466  #2 in the rank of 288       
1   hotel   gt9444  #48 in the rank of 340      
2   hotel   dfa887  #12 in the rank of 7414     
3   hotel   fgfd81  #1 in the rank of 8792
4   hotel   fsf887  #70 in the rank of 245
```

In my coding, I tried to merge it with

```
df_hotel["details"] = (df_hotel["details"] + df_hotel["details2"])
```

However, it fails and it gives out a result with all nan values in the columns "details".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

`replace()` for replacing string `'nan'`(if any if 'nan' is actual NaN then you can skip this step and directly run `fillna()`) to actual `NaN` and `fillna()` to filling those NaN's

```
df_hotel= df_hotel.replace('nan',float('NaN'),regex=True)
df_hotel["details"]=df_hotel["details"].fillna(df_hotel.pop("details2"))
```

output of `df_hotel`:

```
    type    id          details
0   hotel   df9466      #2 in rank of 288
1   hotel   gt9444      #48 in rank of 340
2   hotel   dfa887      #12 in rank of 7414
3   hotel   fgfd81      #1 in rank of 8792
4   hotel   fsf887      #70 in rank of 245
```

Answer (score 1):

`NaN` plus anything will be `NaN`. Instead, we can use [`Series.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) and set the fill_value to the empty string.

```
df_hotel['details'] = (
    df_hotel["details"].add(df_hotel["details2"], fill_value='')
)
```

Alternatively we could [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) both Series and add with `+`:

```
df_hotel["details"] = (df_hotel["details"].fillna('') +
                       df_hotel["details2"].fillna(''))
```

`df_hotel`:

```
    type      id              details            details2
0  hotel  df9466    #2 in rank of 288                 NaN
1  hotel  gt9444   #48 in rank of 340                 NaN
2  hotel  dfa887  #12 in rank of 7414                 NaN
3  hotel  fgfd81   #1 in rank of 8792  #1 in rank of 8792
4  hotel  fsf887   #70 in rank of 245  #70 in rank of 245
```

---

We can [`pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) `details2` if we want to remove from the DataFrame:

```
df_hotel['details'] = (
    df_hotel["details"].add(df_hotel.pop("details2"), fill_value='')
)
```

or

```
df_hotel["details"] = (df_hotel["details"].fillna('') +
                       df_hotel.pop("details2").fillna(''))
```

`df_hotel`:

```
    type      id              details
0  hotel  df9466    #2 in rank of 288
1  hotel  gt9444   #48 in rank of 340
2  hotel  dfa887  #12 in rank of 7414
3  hotel  fgfd81   #1 in rank of 8792
4  hotel  fsf887   #70 in rank of 245
```